# Fantasy book series about a girl who finds her power as a witch/healer

Tags: story-identification, books, witches

I’m trying to remember the name of a book series from the '80s/'90s, set in medieval times, about a girl who finds her power as a witch/healer through the series.  I believe the main character is called Sita, but it’s not Hindu or from India at all.  More a European setting.

I read them early 2000s but the books were older, borrowed from a friend. There was 3 in the series, I believe. They were paperback and the covers were brown/tan tones with illustrations of the main character in non-specific scenes.

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/82623/ya-book-about-a-young-powerful-female-caster-attending-a-school-that-trains-in-m

Answer (score 9):

This might be The Black Magician trilogy by Trudi Canavan. The first book is [The Magician's Guild](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/28249.The_Magicians_Guild), first published in 2001, a little late for the question.

It has a European fantasy setting, is a trilogy with young girl becoming a magician (the term witch is not generally used, perhaps in a historical context in the 2nd story line) with a focus on healing. The main character is Sonea, a girl from a poor family who unexpectedly discovers she has magic during the annual 'purge' when such folk are cleared from town by the eponymous guild.

Tan covers with non specific scenes.

[image: 2005 Covers]